# 'cache swap' filesystem for SSD/HDD combo?

Tags: linux, ssd, filesystems, swap, hard-drive-cache

As we all know, Solid State Drives (SSD) are expensive ($/Gb) but they are quick to access. I'm wondering if there exists a sort of software-kernel-level 'cache swap' filesystem technology; the idea of such filesystem is that it keeps a cache of frequently accessed files on the main HDD, so;

- you get the benefits of SSD speed access for 90% of circumstances
- you get the benefits of cheap long-term storage for files that have not been used in a while

Comment: there is bcache (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bcache) and flashcache (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashcache) - it works on the block layer and not file layer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this article: [the best of SSD and HDD worlds](http://www.pcworld.com/article/237496/the_best_of_both_worlds_an_ssd_and_a_hdd.html)

Basically the simplest and cheapest approach for getting SSD speed benefits without breaking your bank is to use a small SSD (16 ~ 32Gb should be more than enough to reap 80% of performance benefits) disk to keep the `/` partition where all system and applications files are kept (those are what mostly affect the startup performance I/O bottleneck anyways)  and `/users`, where all the personal data is stored, in the HDD.

This has an additional side-benefit; system files are updated less often than user files, so it means the average lifespan of the SSD is largely extended by confining it to a read-mostly-write-rarely filesystem

Answer (score 2):

Your idea motivated me. Well I have got [Dragonfly OS](http://www.dragonflybsd.org/) that maybe suits your need. As stated there:
*DragonFly is uniquely positioned to take advantage of the wide availability of affordable Solid Storage Devices (SSDs), by making use of swap space to cache filesystem data and meta-data. This feature, commonly referred to as "swapcache", can give a significant boost to both server and workstation workloads, with a very minor hardware investment.*

This is a [online documentation](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=swapcache) of the " swapcache" functionality which might help you get further.

Comment: Its a BSD OS. As stated there:
_DragonFly is uniquely positioned to take advantage of the wide availability of affordable Solid Storage Devices (SSDs), by making use of swap space to cache filesystem data and meta-data_

See the cacheswap documentation [here](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=swapcache) and view full site [here](http://www.dragonflybsd.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[ZFS L2ARC](https://blogs.oracle.com/brendan/entry/test) is precisely doing that. Although there is a [native ZFS implementation for Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/) and a [FUSE based one](http://zfs-fuse.net/), this kernel might not be the optimal choice here.

I would recommend OSes with native ZFS support like [Solaris 11](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/zfs-338092.html), OpenSolaris/[Illumos based distributions](http://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/About+illumos#Aboutillumos-TheillumosFamily) or [FreeBSD](http://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFS).

Answer (score 0):

Intel's newest chipsets support caching for an installation on a hard drive with a small SSD (in fact, they're selling 20GB SSDs intended for this use).  They call it '[Smart Response Technology](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/CS-032826.htm)'.  There are a few vendors who've been putting proprietary versions of this on motherboards as well for the last year or so, but I can't speak for the specifics of those.

There are also some manufacturers making '[hybrid hard drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive)', which are essentially a variant of this.  They're a platter drive with some NAND onboard, but I think it's primarily used for buffering more than caching.  They're probably a little more cost effective, but nowhere near as fast as using a real SSD for it.  (They're still faster than normal hard drives, though.)